# Print/save interactive report created using Rmarkdown and Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have an interactive `Rmarkdown` document which embeds a few shiny apps that generates graphs based on user inputs.

After I am happy with the graphs generated, I would like to save the report (so that it becomes static).

I have opened the report in my browser (Chrome), and tried printing to pdf. It sort of works, however some figures are cut into two by the page break.

Does anyone know what is the best way to print/save such reports?

Comment: You want to automaticly save a report from your shyny App ?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a bit tricky but this is what i use on my app to save `html plot` on pdf or png format.

### Instal wkhtmltopdf

> [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) and wkhtmltoimage are open source (LGPLv3) command
>   line tools to render HTML into PDF and various image formats using the
>   Qt WebKit rendering engine. These run entirely "headless" and do not
>   require a display or display service.

### Use it in R

This allow you to convert a `html`file into `pdf`or `img`.
In my `ShinyApp` i use inside a `downloadHandler()` function somthing like this :

```
system("wkhtmltopdf   --enable-javascript --javascript-delay 2000 plot.html plot.pdf")
```

I think for your example you could simply convert your `html` by using :

```
system("wkhtmltopdf yourFile.html yourFile.pdf")
```

Comment: I get the error `Warning message:
running command 'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf temp.html temp.pdf' had status 127` 
I have set the working directory, added wkhtmltopdf in systems path. Any idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can this be done when the shiny app is hosted on shinyapps.io?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a download button on the ui.R as:

`downloadButton('report', 'Download PDF'`)

And the corresponding server.R code:

```
library(knitr)
output$report = downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("Report_", <date/identifier>, ".pdf", sep="")
      },

      content = function(file) {
        rnw <- normalizePath('input.rnw') # assuming you wrote the code to display the graphs etc in this file
        owd <- setwd(tempdir())
        on.exit(setwd(owd))
        file.copy(rnw, 'input.rnw')

        out = knit2pdf(rnw, clean=TRUE)
        file.rename(out, file) 
      }
    )
```